# How to change title of Drawer navigator header when the screen changes?

Tags: javascript, react-native, navigation-drawer

I am very new to `React`/`React-Native` and `Javascript` as well but not to programming in general. I recently started learning `React-Native` and have been watching the `The Net Ninja`'s playlist on YouTube which is 3-4 years old. He does some things that are not available or have been changed in the newer API. Most of the stuff I am able to fix my self, but I can't seem figure this one out.

How do I change the title on the header of `Drawer Navigator` when the screen changes?

Here is how my app looks like,

I have 2 `Stack Navigator` screens `Home` and `About`

```js
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/native-stack';

import Home from '../screens/home';
import Reviews from '../screens/reviews';

const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();

export default function HomeStack() {
    return (
        <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="Home">
            <Stack.Group screenOptions={{
                /* headerStyle: { */
                /*     backgroundColor: '#eee', */
                /*     height: 80, */
                /* }, */
                /* headerTintColor: '#444', */
                header: () => null,
                headerShown: true,
            }}>
                <Stack.Screen
                    name='HomeScreen'
                    component={Home}
                    options={{ title: 'GameZone' }}
                />
                <Stack.Screen
                    name='ReviewsScreen'
                    component={Reviews}
                    options={{ title: 'Reviews' }}
                />
            </Stack.Group>
        </Stack.Navigator>
    );
};
```

```js
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';

import About from '../screens/about';

const Stack = createStackNavigator();

export default function AboutStack() {
    return (
        <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="Home" screenOptions={{ headerMode: 'screen' }}>
            <Stack.Group screenOptions={{
                /* headerStyle: { */
                /*     backgroundColor: '#eee', */
                /*     height: 80, */
                /* }, */
                /* headerTintColor: '#444', */
                header: () => null,
                headerShown: false,
            }}>
                <Stack.Screen
                    name='AboutScreen'
                    component={About}
                    options={{ title: 'About GameZone' }}
                />
            </Stack.Group>
        </Stack.Navigator>
    );
};
```

and I then I have a `Drawer Navigator`,

```js
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createDrawerNavigator } from "@react-navigation/drawer";

import AboutStack from './aboutStack';
import HomeStack from './homeStack';

const RootDrawerNavigator = createDrawerNavigator();

export default function Drawer() {
    return (
        <NavigationContainer>
            <RootDrawerNavigator.Navigator initialRouteName='GameZone' backBehavior='history'>
                <RootDrawerNavigator.Group screenOptions={{
                    headerStyle: {
                        backgroundColor: '#ccc',
                        height: 80,
                    },
                    headerTintColor: '#444',
                }}>
                    <RootDrawerNavigator.Screen
                        name='Home'
                        component={HomeStack}
                        options={{ title: 'Home' }}
                    />
                    <RootDrawerNavigator.Screen
                        name='About'
                        component={AboutStack}
                        options={{ title: 'About' }}
                    />
                </RootDrawerNavigator.Group>
            </RootDrawerNavigator.Navigator>
        </NavigationContainer>
    );
}
```

Now no matter which screen I go to I only see title from the screen defined in `Drawer Navigator` which are `Home` or `About` on the header and not from the other screens defined under `HomeStack`.

This is the `Home` screen,
[image]

This is the `Drawer`
[image]

This is the `About` screen
[image]

This is the `Reviews` screen
[image]

Home and Reviews screens are part of `HomeStack` and whenever I click on a item from home screen it should say `Reviews` as I am in the reviews screen then.

Also because I have disabled the header in the stack navigator, I don't have a back button anymore.

Answer (score 1):

In your drawer navigator file, you have named reviews screen as home. Your screen's name can be changed by changing those.

```
                <RootDrawerNavigator.Screen
                    name='Home' // here
                    component={HomeStack}
                    options={{ title: 'Home' }} // here
                />
                <RootDrawerNavigator.Screen
                    name='About'
                    component={AboutStack}
                    options={{ title: 'About' }}
                />
```

Comment: This is the `HomeStack` not the home screen. Changing the title here to `options={{ title: 'TestTitle' }}` for example changes the header title for both the home and reviews screen. See this link for a short demo video https://0x0.st/oC5X.mp4